# Sorting out Switch cases/If Statement with multiple arguments, new to Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, javascript-objects

Okay, this is kind of a specific case, so I had trouble searching for a similar problem.

I'm using Angular and linking to Firebase back-end to try and return a true or false value. I'm having trouble making sense of a set of 4 either true or false values under the respective properties `{yesterdayAm: false, yesterdayPm: false, todayAm: false, todayPm: false}` of the variable of the Firebase download object `ref`. I'm getting the correct and predictable calls back when I run it simply, I'm literally stupid for not comprehending the `if` or `switch` expressions Angular/Javascript side. Help me return the right values?

I'll start from the view:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 ">
<div class="dexbowl"><img ng-src="{{ isFed('yesterdayAm') }}"/></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="dexbowl"><img ng-src="{{ isFed('yesterdayPm') }}"/></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
<div class="dexbowl"><img ng-click="feed('todayAm')" ng-src="{{ isFed('todayAm') }}"/></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5">
<div class="dexbowl"><img ng-click="feed('todayPm')" ng-src="{{ isFed('todayPm') }}"/></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to feed a dog by clicking a button. The 4 `isFed('[dayAm/Pm]')` functions called from the `img`'s `ng-src`. These get returned the image files for their respective states. The states are as follows in the `$scope`:

```
    var blueFilled = 'images/dexterbluefilled.svg';
    var satBlueFilled = 'images/SATdexterbluefilled.svg'; /* not used yet */
    var blueEmpty = 'images/dexterblueempty.svg';
    var satBlueEmpty = 'images/SATdexterblueempty.svg'; /*not used yet */
```

They get returned through this function in the `$scope`:

```
if (Fed.getInitState(when)) {
        return blueFilled;          
    } else {
        return blueEmpty;
};
```

You might ask, well what is this `Fed.getInitState(when)` function that's passing along the `todayAm/todayPm/yesterdayAm/yesterdayPm` argument. And you're right to. `Fed` is a `service` (or factory) that loads from Firebase, and is as follows:

```
getInitState: function(when) {
            var value = ref[when];
                return value;
                /* value to equal "true" or "false", depending on server state of todayAm, todayPm, yesterdayAm, yesterdayPm */
            },
```

Again, the `ref` object is:
`{yesterdayAm: false, yesterdayPm: false, todayAm: false, todayPm: false}`

Now for the problem:
Everything gets back to the view fine with the above `if` function that returns the `var blueEmpty` and `var blueFilled` image paths to the view. It all works. I can't for the *life* of me figure out how to implement the other two image paths: `var satBlueEmpty` and `var satBlueFilled`.

I'm trying to return only the 2 "`sat`" image paths to the view for the 2 properties: `yesterdayAm` and `yesterdayPm`. I've been trying to work with the `$scope` `if` statement to funnel the `blueEmpty` and `blueFilled` to the `todayAm`,`todayPm`, and the `sat` image path variables to the `yesterdayAm`,`yesterdayPm` properties.

I've tried using `switch` and nested `if` statements to return the right values (true/false), but I'm feeling really dumb and can't for the life of me sort this out.

I'm a little new to Javascript and Angular and this is my first full app to try and finish completely. I think the direction here is to go to feed the right values from the `Fed` service. Can anyone help me out with this one? I'm stuck.

*edit

I thought this nested `if` function might work, but to no avail:

```
    $scope.isFed = function(when, which) {} 
        if (Fed.getInitState(when)) {   
            if (which === sat) {
                    return satBlueFilled;
                } else {
                    return blueFilled;          
            } else {
                if (which === notSat);
                    return satBlueFilled;
                } else {
                    return satBlueEmpty;
                }
            }
        };
```

*edit 2

Following @Steve Lang's advice I'm working on creating a switch statement in `Fed.getInitState` to return a value `1`,`2`,`3`, or `4` to the controller function `$scope.isFed`. I have the following so far:

```
getInitState: function(when) {          
                var trueOrFalse = ref[when];
                console.log('when: ' + when + ' ' + 'value: ' + value);
                switch (trueOrFalse) {
                    case 'todayAm':
                        return 1;
                    case 'todayPm':
                        return 2;
                    case 'yesterdayAm':
                        return 3;
                    case 'yesterdayPm':
                        return 4;
                }       
            },
```

Can I add an `&` operator to the case to control for which value `when` is equal to? It seems like I need an `if` statement nested into a switch...

Comment: I'm not seeing any connection to Firebase or AngularFire in this question.

Comment: The view above uses ng-src and ng-click directives. The data is coming from Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fed.getInitState()` should be able to return more than true or false. Let's say `Fed.getInitState()` returns a value between 1 to 4, then you can specify as follows:

```
$scope.isFed = function(when) {
    switch (Fed.getInitState(when)) {
        case 1:
            return blueFilled;
        case 2:
            return blueEmpty;
        case 3:
            return satBlueFilled;
        case 4:
            return satBlueEmpty;
    }
};
```

**Update in response to comment**

You can use getInitState() as it originally was:

```
getInitState: function(when) {
    var value = ref[when];
    return value;
}
```

But the ref object should be something like so:

```
{yesterdayAm: 1, yesterdayPm: 2, todayAm: 3, todayPm: 4}
```

Comment: Would `Fed.getInitState()` also need a `switch` function to return 1 through 4? What would be the difference between placing the switch with the service `Fed` and putting it in the controller?